# RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available! Although torch.cuda.is_available() is true

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

When I run torch.cuda.is_available() it shows true. And Cuda is always work fine in all projects that need GPU. However, in a [project](https://github.com/LiYingwei/ShapeTextureDebiasedTraining) when I run python imagenet.py -a resnet50 --data %DATA% --mixbn --evaluate --load %CKPT% , it returns RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available

Could you please give me some clue?

Comment: Just to clarify, the command `python -c "import torch; print( torch.cuda.is_available())` would print `true`?

Comment: Hi @FlyingTeller is the command is correct? I ran it with one `"` and two. But either way it says `Unable to initialize device PRN`. However, if I run `python ` then  `import torch` then `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `true`